# Starting gdbserver failed (VS2017 --> yocto)

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2017, gdbserver

I am using VS2017 to compile and debug my cross platform C application on linux. With my Raspberry Pi it is working perfectly, but now I tryed it to debug it on a yocto system. Compilation works, but if I want to debug I am getting following messge: Starting gdbserver failed, this is unexpected and indicative of an incompatible or broken shell. Example command used on the shell: "echo 1; gdbserver; echo 2". We expected "1".

[Visual Studio Message Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmyAr.png)

On my remote machine gdbserver 7.10.1 is installed.

Comment: Might be related to this: https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/119 . You could try debugging in `gdb` mode. What response do you get when you enter the command line directly into an ssh command window?

Comment: Thank you stanthomas. Debugging with gdb works as expected. The problems seems to be at gdbserver.