# Error while using Visual studio Remote GDB debugger

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, gdbserver

I have tried with no success for a good 4 hours to debug a program using Visual studio remote debugger and I keep getting the same error message:

> could not launch gdbserver. gdbserver could either be missing on your system and need to be installed, or it failed to start the program.

-My attempted solutions so far:

1. I logged into the Linux (fedora)remote system and installed gdb, and all the required depencises. However I get another message saying:

> no package gdbserver available.

2. Is there a difference between gdb and gdbserver?
3. Realizing that I was not succeeding with the Fedora I decided to try and install gdb/dependencies on a Centos7 system. Going to Visual studio and launching the remote debugger. I still get the same error message.

Your expertise will be very appreciated

Comment: Is it the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237924/starting-gdbserver-failed-vs2017-yocto?noredirect=1#comment77514657_45237924

Comment: Or it might be a firewall problem : lookup "gdbserver port"

Answer (score 3):

i installed the gdbserver this works for me on the raspberry pi

*sudo apt-get install gdbserver*